# Laravel query with union and count

Tags: php, sql, laravel, union

I have the queries:

```
$dateToday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(Carbon::today()));

$countTodayMatchOccurrences = DB::table('occurrences')->select('date')->whereDate('date', '=', $dateToday);
$countTodayMatch = DB::table('matches')->select('date')->whereDate('date', '=', $dateToday)->union($countTodayMatchOccurrences)->count();
```

And I have the table, look like this:
Table `matches`:

[image: Matches table]

And table `occurrences`:

[image: occurrences]

I don't know why, but my query does not work correctly. My query returns `2`, but should return `4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to view the actual queries that are run and verify that they are what you want. I would also run the whole thing as one query.

I would also normalize the database a bit more. Add a model URL and a corresponding urls table with id, match_id, url, accepted.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are forgetting a

`->get()` for your first query.

```
$dateToday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(Carbon::today()));

$countTodayMatchOccurrences = DB::table('occurrences')->select('date')->whereDate('date', '=', $dateToday)->get();
$countTodayMatch = DB::table('matches')->select('date')->whereDate('date', '=', $dateToday)->union($countTodayMatchOccurrences)->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when I added `get()` Laravel returned me error: Method getBindings does not exist.